# MongoDB: Update all fields

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Is there a way I can update every field in a MongoDB document without just listing all the fields, which might change later? Something like this?

```
db.update(
    {foo:"bar"},
    {$unset: {{}:""}}
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the cogency of an operation like this. How are you updating all of the fields meaningfully without considering their specific types or values? It looks like you are trying to unset the fields or set them to a default, null-like value. What does it mean to unset every field in a document? Isn't it really just removing the document? Are you excluding `_id` and other immutable fields (shard key!) somehow? What is the default value for the possible field types? What is the default value for a field that can be an integer or an array of integers in a data model? It's also dangerous to try to do something like this, especially with flexible schemas. Needing to do the above operation indicates a good chance that you need to rethink your data model.

Comment: I am indeed essentially removing the document. Remove() would be better, but it doesn't work in a capped collection, and I can't switch to an uncapped collection yet (ridiculously tight memory constraints right now.) In any case, I take this to mean that it can't be done.